# Accomplish with Triggers the job of events from a TextBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

Hi i am trying to put what i am doing in the events from Code Behind in Triggers of a Style who is being applied in a TextBox. What i want is to prevent using the Code Behind to do that and use Triggers. Is there any way to accomplish this?

My Textbox

```
<TextBox Name="myTextBox"  Style="{StaticResource txtBoxStyle}"/>
```

My style

```
<Style x:Key="txtBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Silver"/>
    <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="6"/>
</Style>
```

The Events from Code Behind

```
private void myTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myTextBox.Text.Length == 0)
        myTextBox.Text = "000000";
}

private void myTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myTextBox.Text == "000000")
        myTextBox.Clear();
}

private void myTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9) && e.Key != Key.Back)
        e.Handled = true;
}

private void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myTextBox.Text == "000000")
        myTextBox.Foreground = Brushes.Silver;
    else
    {                
        myTextBox.Foreground = Brushes.Black;

        if(myTextBox.Text.Length == 6)
            myButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        else
            myButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Using triggers for this logic is not a good idea and will in all likelihood fail because of its self-referencing (causes a stack-overflow), value converters are also a bit problematic. To encapsulate complex logic and apply it via a Style use an [attached behavior](http://www.bjoernrochel.de/2009/08/19/the-attached-behavior-pattern/).

---

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value=""/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="000000"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="000000"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Text" Value=""/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="000000">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Silver"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <!-- If (Text != "000000") Foreground = Brushes.Black -->
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

The logic which sets the visibility of the button should not be handled in this style but by the button. The key-down event cannot be translated.

Button style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/> <!-- Normal state -->
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=myButton}" Value="6">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: If i do this `<Setter Property="Text" Value="000000"/>` has default setter (out of triggers), when the TextBox gain focus gives me this exception **Text' Storyboard.TargetProperty path contains nonanimatable property 'Text'.**. Can you explain me why?

Comment: Right, you cannot animate it; using an animation is not necessary anyway, since we're dealing with a state, not an event. I changed the answer to use setters which should work and yield the same results.

Comment: Well, that is unfortunate, but this might be the closest you can get using a Style. I myself would probably not do it like this, basically you just want an empty string to be shown as 6 zeros it seems, for that i would use a binding with a ValueConverter.

Comment: Actually this causes a stack-overflow exception for me. Basically you should never use triggers whose condition is the property that you will set if the trigger fires.

Comment: For me too if i use Text="", but i tried with that and with Text="{x:Null}" but none of them worked.

Comment: So you say that is better to do with a Converter how you suggested above in a comment?

Comment: I edited my answer; i think you should use a attached behavior, see the link if you do not know how that works.